# Incorrect output while using methods in recursion. The return statement in a method returns an integer at the end of the output

Tags: java

```
package abcde;

public class Abcde{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(recursion(97));
    }

    public static int recursion (int n) {
        for ( int i = n; i< 123; i++)
        {
            String achar = new Character((char)i).toString();
            System.out.print(achar);

        }
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

The desired output has to be abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz while the output is abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-1

I dont want the -1 at the end.
When i change the input type to void, the method does not work.

What can we do about it?

Comment: Methods that are called "recursion" are generally expected to be, well, recursive :)

Comment: Does anyone notice any recursion here?

Comment: This is not using recursion. It is a for loop inside a method called recursion().

Answer (score 4):

The final `-1` gets printed outside the `recursion` method: `main()` prints what `recursion` returns, which happens to be `-1`.

If you change the return type of `recursion` to `void`, you need to call it as a method, not as an expression. In other words, you can no longer call `println(recursion(97))` because `println` expects a value to print.

As a side note, in order to be recursive a method needs to have a code path that calls the same method, directly or indirectly. Since the "calling itself" feature is missing from your `recursion` method, consider renaming it to `iteration`.

Answer (score 2):

rewrite it to:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    noRecursion(97);
}

public static void noRecursion (int n) {
            //^^^^
    for (int i = n; i< 123; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)i);
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your `recursion` function doesn't return anything **but** `-1`, but It does print all of the other characters before it returns.

if you change it to

```
public static void notRecursion (int n) {
    for ( int i = n; i< 123; i++)
    {
        String achar = new Character((char)i).toString();
        System.out.print(achar);

    }
}
```

and then just call it from your main like

```
notRecursion(97);
```

It will print what you want it to print

---

Or

```
public static String recursion (int n) 
{
    if(n >97 +1)
    {
        System.out.print(recursion(n-1)); 
    }

    String achar = new Character((char)n).toString();
    return(achar)
}
```

and then call it with

```
System.out.println(recursion(123));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the above code using recursion but the output is get is from z to a rather than a to z. I also see { in the beginning of output . Help !

Comment: @user2275925 i had an issue on the edge case, sry about that.  Also, if you want to print it in reverse, than you just have to do it backwards.  I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Choose pure functions over side effects:

```
public static String iteration (int n) {
    final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c = (char)n; c < 123; c++)
        b.append(c);

    return b.toString();
}
```

Now you can call this method as you are calling it now, and print its result.